# What does `&method(:method_ name)` mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I was trying to create a class that has a private class method. I want this private class method available to be used inside an instance method.

The following was my first attempt:

```
class Animal
  class << self
    def public_class_greeter(name)
      private_class_greeter(name)
    end

  private
    def private_class_greeter(name)
      puts "#{name} greets private class method"
    end
  end

  def public_instance_greeter(name)
    self.class.private_class_greeter(name)
  end
end
```

`Animal.public_class_greeter('John')` works fine, printing `John greets private class method`.

However, `Animal.new.public_instance_greeter("John")` throws an error: `NoMethodError: private method 'private_class_greeter' called for Animal:Class`.

That is expected, as the invocation `self.class.private_class_greeter` is same as `Animal.private_class_greeter`, which obviously throws an error.

After searching on how this can be fixed, I came up with the following code, that does the job:

```
class Animal
  class << self
    def public_class_greeter(name)
      private_class_greeter(name)
    end

  private
    def private_class_greeter(name)
      puts "#{name} greets private class method"
    end
  end

  define_method :public_instance_greeter, &method(:private_class_greeter)
end
```

I don't exactly understand what is happening here: `&method(:private_class_greeter)`.

Could you please explain what does this mean?

If I were to replace:

```
define_method :public_instance_greeter, &method(:private_class_greeter)
```

with:

```
def public_instance_greeter
  XYZ
end
```

then, what should be the content in place of `XYZ`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**How does Ruby parse `&method(:private_class_greeter)`?**

The expression `&method(:private_class_greeter)` is

- the value of the method call `method(:private_class_greeter)`
- prefixed with the **`&`** operator.

---

**What does the `method` method do?**

The [**`method`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-method) method looks up the specified method name in the current context and returns a `Method` object that represents it. Example in `irb`:

```
def foo
  "bar"
end

my_method = method(:foo)
#=> #<Method: Object#foo>
```

Once you have this method, you can do various things with it:

```
my_method.call
#=> "bar"

my_method.source_location   # gives you the file and line the method was defined on
#=> ["(irb)", 5]

# etc.
```

---

**What is the `&` operator for?**

The **`&`** operator is used to **pass a `Proc` as a block to a method** that expects a block to be passed to it. It also implicitly calls the `to_proc` method on the value you pass in, in order to convert values that are not `Proc` into a `Proc`.

The `Method` class implements `to_proc` — it returns the contents of the method as a `Proc`. Therefore, you can prefix a `Method` instance with `&` and pass it as a block to another method:

```
def call_block
  yield
end

call_block &my_method   # same as `call_block &my_method.to_proc`
#=> "bar"
```

The `define_method` method just happens to take a block with the contents of the new method that is being defined. In your example, `&method(:private_class_greeter)` passes in the existing `private_class_greeter` method as a block.

---

**Is this how `&:symbol` works?**

Yes. **`Symbol`** implements `to_proc` so that you can simplify your code like this:

```
["foo", "bar"].map(&:upcase)
#=> ["FOO", "BAR"]

# this is equivalent to:
["foo", "bar"].map { |item| item.upcase }

# because
:upcase.to_proc

# returns this proc:
Proc { |val| val.send(:upcase) }
```

---

**How can I replicate `&method(:private_class_greeter)`?**

You can pass in a block that calls the target method:

```
define_method :public_instance_greeter do |name|
  self.class.send(:private_class_greeter, name)
end
```

Of course, then you don't need to use `define_method` anymore, which results in the same solution Eric mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45014207/1242470):

```
def public_instance_greeter(name)
  self.class.send(:private_class_greeter, name)
end
```

Comment: Nicely explained.

Comment: `&` **does not** pass a `Method` instance as a block. It does not distinguish the parameter by type at all. It implicitly calls `to_proc` on a receiver (`Method` instance in that case,) and passes the result (`Proc` instance) to the method. Absolutely the same as `&:to_s` calls `Symbol#to_proc` on `:to_s` symbol and passes the `Proc` further.

Comment: I was simplifying the explanation on purpose. But I suppose I can add some explanation about `to_proc`...

Comment: Well, the wording “the `&` operator is used to pass [..] a Method as a block” is just wrong, that’s why I suggest to somehow mention `to_proc` at least.

Comment: Good catch! Updated the answer to be more precise.

Comment: I have no ability to check right now, but I am positive it does not check the parameter type at all and calls `to_proc` on everything, including `Proc` instances. `Proc#to_proc` is noop, that’s why it brings no harm.

Comment: I was able to verify this. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Could you please answer the last part of the question too?

BTW, @eric-duminil's asnwer works.

Comment: Added an answer for the last part.

Comment: Sorry, did not notice that you answered with the exact same code before I did. Updated the post to reference your answer.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is spot on now!

Comment: Note that `define_method` also accepts a `Proc`, an `UnboundMethod` or a `Method`, so applying the `&` operator in this case is not actually necessary.

Answer (score 3):

First, take good care with your indentation. `private` should be 2 spaces to the right: it gives the impression that `public_instance_greeter` is private otherwise.

If you don't care about encapsulation, you could simply use [`Kernel#send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-send):

```
class Animal
  class << self
    def public_class_greeter(name)
      private_class_greeter(name)
    end

    private
    def private_class_greeter(name)
      puts "#{name} greets private class method"
    end
  end

  def public_instance_greeter(name)
    self.class.send(:private_class_greeter, name)
  end
end

Animal.public_class_greeter('John')
# John greets private class method
Animal.new.public_instance_greeter("John")
# John greets private class method
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about the indentation. I am aware of popular style guides. I think negative indenting `private` keyword helps to easily identify where private methods start. That is the reason why I prefer indenting the `private` keyword to root level.

I know this is against most of the style guides. Do you think my thought process makes sense?

Comment: @SatyaramBV: If you (and your colleagues) can read it, that's fine for me. One way to avoid this problem would be to move the ` class << self` to the end of the `Animal` class.

Comment: @SatyaramBV FWIW, all the teams I've worked on have prefered the outdented accessibility keywords as well.