# Can you pass arguments to the method in `&method(:method_ name)` in ruby?

Tags: ruby, methods

After reading: [What does `&method(:method_ name)` mean in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013455/what-does-methodmethod-name-mean-in-ruby), I somewhat understand you can pass methods into the &method but is it possible to pass arguments into, in this case, method_name?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695653/can-you-supply-arguments-to-the-mapmethod-syntax-in-ruby?rq=1

Comment: `[1].map &method(:puts)` is passing `1` as an argument already. it's not baked into the syntax to pass additional args, but you can use higher-order functions or zip.